# Increase approximation probability in approxPolyDP() in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, polygons

I am making a system for shape identification in *OpenCV-Python*.
`approxPolyDP()` is a best way to find a shape. I am using it for find square, pentagon, etc.

But, sometimes `approxPolyDP()` is unable to get the polygon exactly. Therefore `Blur()` and `Thresholding()` are used. However it is also not enough.

If I get a filtered image like this:

[image: Image before processing]

After `Threshold()` and `Blur()`:

[image: Image after processing]

How can I improve approximation probability?

Please give me some idea/system/algorithm for increased approximation probability.

Comment: @Bogdan Bogdanov why you edit my post?can you give me solutions?

Comment: Sorry @NSiri, I have 2 typos. I edit question so it can be more readable. You can read [this](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask good questions in Stack Overflow. Sorry for typos.

Comment: ok..thanks.I'm a new one..I have approved your edits

Comment: No problem, when you get enought reputation you can also make edit to questions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “not enough”? What aspect of the result would you like improved? (Also, adding “thanks” to a question is [considered fluff on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions)).

Comment: My final target is get number of coners of polygon very accurately.Blur() and Threshold() are help to approxPolyDP().But,those two algorithms not enough to achieve my target.
Can I add more methods/algorithm to get more accurate result from approxPolyDP()?
Have more filtering methods/algorithm for get accurate result?

Answer (score 0):

Approximation probability of 'approxPolyDP()' can be increased by using **epsilon** parameter.

cv2.approxPolyDP(curve, **epsilon**, closed[, approxCurve])

Think,You have like this(black only),

[image: Approximated polygon]

if you increase **epsilon** 'approxPolyDP()' ignore most nearest carve point and change detected shape.
While you increasing **epsilon** 'approxPolyDP()' ignore A point first(because,A  point is nearest to red line than B point to green line).Then you increasing more it will ignore B point.

So,You also done threshold,blure and do more presetting,you may have some shaking point in detected polygon and you may be unable to  get exact shape.**epsilon**is very useful like that situation.